# I get the error "AWS account ID not found for provider" when setting up LocalStack in on-premises environment

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm attempting to set up LocalStack on my local environment to prepare for an AWS certification using this [GitHub project](https://github.com/R1w/aws-localstack-lab.git).
So far, everything appears to be working correctly, but I've encountered an issue during the "terraform plan" phase, specifically related to the "access_key" and "secret_key."
I would greatly appreciate your assistance with this matter.

[image: AWS account ID not found for provider]